# Datastructure for Matrix or HashMap in d3.js

Tags: matrix, dictionary, d3.js

I have a data in the form of a matrix with both row and column header.
What would the appropriate data structure in d3 to represent this data,wherein I should be able to fetch each cell based on row and column headers.

Data looks something like below:

```
             Col 1    Col 2   Col 3
    Row 1        2      1.2       5
    Row 2      3.9      9.8      27
    Row 3        7       67      87
```

Please suggest on how should I import this data in d3.js and in what form should I store it.

Comment: I think you didn't get answers because you didn't tag your question well. I will add d3 tag.